# Fail to connect with command create_ap it create hotspot 192.168.10.199

Tags: wifi, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, access-point, hotspot

I have connected the modem to an RPi4 running Ubuntu 20.4 and downloaded the folder for running the 'simcom' command (SIM8200_for_rpi) and the folder for the 'create_ap' command.

Below are the steps I take:

```
sudo ./simcom-cm
create_ap -g <ip> wlan0 wwan0 name pass
```

The 'simcom' command encountered some issues, but they were resolved with a system package update.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/SIM8200_for_RPI/Goonline$ sudo ./simcom-cm 
[03-25_18:23:22:674] Build Version: 2020-07-14 10:20:15
[03-25_18:23:22:674] SIMCOM_CM START...
[03-25_18:23:22:674] ./simcom-cm profile[1] = (null)/(null)/(null)/0, pincode = (null)
[03-25_18:23:22:675] Find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1 idVendor=1e0e idProduct=9001
[03-25_18:23:22:675] Find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1:1.5/net/wwan0
[03-25_18:23:22:675] Find usbnet_adapter = wwan0
[03-25_18:23:22:675] Find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1:1.5/usbmisc/cdc-wdm0
[03-25_18:23:22:675] Find qmichannel = /dev/cdc-wdm0
[03-25_18:23:22:676] netcard driver = qmi_wwan
[03-25_18:23:22:731] cdc_wdm_fd = 7
[03-25_18:23:22:828] Get clientWDS = 14
[03-25_18:23:22:861] Get clientDMS = 1
[03-25_18:23:22:893] Get clientNAS = 2
[03-25_18:23:22:925] Get clientUIM = 1
[03-25_18:23:22:956] Get clientWDA = 1
[03-25_18:23:22:988] requestBaseBandVersion MPSS.HI.2.5-01229-SDX55_CPEALL_PACK-1.27120.6.30100.2  1  [Apr 24 2023 11:00:00]
[03-25_18:23:23:053] requestGetSIMStatus SIMStatus: SIM_READY
[03-25_18:23:23:085] requestGetProfile[1] mobile.vodafone.it///0
[03-25_18:23:23:117] requestRegistrationState2 MCC: 222, MNC: 10, PS: Attached, DataCap: LTE
[03-25_18:23:23:148] requestQueryDataCall IPv4ConnectionStatus: DISCONNECTED
[03-25_18:23:23:212] requestRegistrationState2 MCC: 222, MNC: 10, PS: Attached, DataCap: LTE
[03-25_18:23:23:245] requestSetupDataCall WdsConnectionIPv4Handle: 0x33825e00
[03-25_18:23:23:308] requestQueryDataCall IPv4ConnectionStatus: CONNECTED
[03-25_18:23:23:341] ifconfig wwan0 up
[03-25_18:23:23:350] busybox udhcpc -f -n -q -t 5 -s /usr/share/udhcpc/default.script -i wwan0
udhcpc: started, v1.30.1
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending select for 100.104.76.119
udhcpc: lease of 100.104.76.119 obtained, lease time 7200
[03-25_18:23:23:521] /usr/share/udhcpc/default.script: Resetting default routes
SIOCDELRT: No such process
[03-25_18:23:23:536] /usr/share/udhcpc/default.script: Adding DNS 10.133.106.158
[03-25_18:23:23:536] /usr/share/udhcpc/default.script: Adding DNS 10.128.28.17
```

The problem now persists with 'create_ap'. It successfully creates an access point with the correct IP, which remains stable for about 10 seconds, if not less, before disappearing (without displaying any errors or warnings on the AP creation screen). During those 10 seconds, if one tries to connect to the access point, it correctly performs the handshake but immediately closes the connection afterward.

```
WARN: brmfmac driver doesn't work properly with virtual interfaces and
      it can cause kernel panic. For this reason we disallow virtual
      interfaces for your adapter.
      For more info: https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/203
WARN: Your adapter does not fully support AP virtual interface, enabling --no-virt
Config dir: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.r7KjHzyq
PID: 2570
Sharing Internet using method: nat
hostapd command-line interface: hostapd_cli -p /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.r7KjHzyq/hostapd_ctrl
WARN: Low entropy detected. We recommend you to install `haveged'
Configuration file: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.r7KjHzyq/hostapd.conf
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr d8:3a:dd:65:bb:2f and ssid "trudi"
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlan0: AP-ENABLED
wlan0: STA 22:db:cb:80:b4:29 IEEE 802.11: associated
wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 22:db:cb:80:b4:29
wlan0: STA 22:db:cb:80:b4:29 RADIUS: starting accounting session 4C93872EEC87D970
wlan0: STA 22:db:cb:80:b4:29 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (WPA)
wlan0: STA 22:db:cb:80:b4:29 WPA: group key handshake completed (WPA)
wlan0: STA 22:db:cb:80:b4:29 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED
22:db:cb:80:b4:29
wlan0: STA e2:01:e2:01:e2:01 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
```

Upon checking via 'ifconfig', indeed, the IP disappears, and if one tries to rerun the 'create_ap' command, it throws an error.

```
WARN: brmfmac driver doesn't work properly with virtual interfaces and
      it can cause kernel panic. For this reason we disallow virtual
      interfaces for your adapter.
      For more info: https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/issues/203
ERROR: Your adapter can not be a station (i.e. be connected) and an AP at the same time
```

Another scenario is having a stable connection that later freezes, but the IP becomes an internal IP of the 192.x.x.x type, which doesn't create a hotspot. Here are two 'ifconfig' outputs taken a few seconds apart:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/trips-main$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d8:3a:dd:65:bb:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 184  bytes 13227 (13.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 184  bytes 13227 (13.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.104.76.119  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 100.104.76.255
        inet6 fe80::da3a:ddff:fe65:bb2f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:3a:dd:65:bb:2f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 5598 (5.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
wwan0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.104.76.119  netmask 255.255.255.240  destination 100.104.76.119
        inet6 fe80::3499:c4ff:948c:b7fb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 42  bytes 4791 (4.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27  bytes 2227 (2.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/trips-main$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d8:3a:dd:65:bb:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 188  bytes 13486 (13.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 188  bytes 13486 (13.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.199  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::da3a:ddff:fe65:bb2f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:3a:dd:65:bb:2f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4  bytes 762 (762.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 65  bytes 9557 (9.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 
wwan0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.104.76.119  netmask 255.255.255.240  destination 100.104.76.119
        inet6 fe80::3499:c4ff:948c:b7fb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 53  bytes 5902 (5.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame
        0
        TX packets 36  bytes 2799 (2.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It doesn't allow access or even the possibility to recreate it without having to reboot the system. We've tried rebooting and the classic "turning off and on again" of the modem, but nothing has changed. We've also tried updating the libraries and updating the create_ap command, even using a graphical interface, but nothing has changed. Has this ever happened to you? Do you know what could be done?

Comment: Network Manager includes an option to create an AP - no need for any other software. I have used on Raspberry Pi OS but expect it should work even on an old Ubuntu.